# SQL update column and use max value of a column for each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to update `Program` table and use max value of `program.programOrder` **+ 1** for each row. `programOrder` has to be unique so I don't want to use the same value for all updates and ideally I want to recalculate max value for each row.

I get the following error:

> You can't specify target table 'p' for update in FROM clause

```
update Program p
set p.programOrder = (select max(programOrder) + 1 from Program)
where isActive = false;
```

I appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.  Probably the simplest uses variables.  That is something like this:

```
select @rn := max(programOrder)
from program;

update Program p
    set p.programOrder = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where isActive = false;
```

Note that such use of variables is deprecated in the most recent version of MySQL, but this is still probably the most convenient method.